# Use Mongo aggregate pipeline to populate response from an array of IDs in an external collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mern

I'm currently working on an app using the MERN stack.

I have a `User` model where a document looks something as follows

```
{
  username: 'Testuser',
  events: {
    favorited: [ObjectId("abcdefg12345678"), ObjectId("hijklmno12345678")]
  } 
}
```

I then have an `Event` model where the documents look something as follows

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("abcdefg12345678"),
    name: 'Party One',
    address: 'Party St'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("hijklmno12345678"),
    name: 'Party Two',
    address: 'Party Lane'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("pqrstuvw12345678"),
    name: 'Party Three'
    address: 'Party Town'
  }
]
```

I want to return an array of only the Event documents that correspond with the `favorited` array in the User document, and I only want to return the Event `name`, and not `address`.

I think I need to use `$lookup` and `$project` but have so far been unsuccessful in my attempts.

My latest attempt looks something like this.

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Event",
      localField: "events.favorited",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "favorite_events"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      name: 1,
    }
  }
])
```

- Updated to change **favorited** array from **strings** to **ObjectIds**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixes:**

- `from` write your actual collection name that you have in database
- `foreignField` pass `_id` to match this field with `events.favorited`
- `as` to return events in `events.favorited` field
- `$project` to exclude `address` field from events `events.favorited.address`

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "events", // correct with yours collection name
      localField: "events.favorited",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "events.favorited"
    }
  },
  { $project: { "events.favorited.address": 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KvTBNgZ010q)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work although it seems to in MongoPlayground. I should have mentioned, but could this be because the **favorited** array is an array of ObjectIds?

Comment: yes perhaps, the favorited array contains string type id or object id type?

Comment: The favorited array is ObjectIds. Updated the question above accordingly

Comment: and what is the type of _id in event collection?

Comment: they are also ObjectId

Comment: so what is the issue? it should work both are having same type.

Comment: Currently it only returns an array with a single object containing the User ObjectId

Comment: make sure you have replaced your actual collection name in `from: "events"` and check other possibilities you are missing something.